# How to resize column grid header in extjs?

Tags: css, extjs, sass, extjs5

I have this grid that has headers in vertical position (**phone header**), and when I try to resize the header's width to **50px** I don't get to see the **header text** anymore (but if I manually drag the header to the left I can see the header text), so my question is: How can I always show the header text even after setting the header size to smaller size.

Please take a look at this line of code:

```
{ text: 'Phone' dataIndex: 'phone', cls: 'grid-header-phone' }
```

Now I'm simply adding a smaller width to it like this:

```
{ text: 'Phone', width: 50, dataIndex: 'phone', cls: 'grid-header-phone' }
```

Here's a working example: [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/boc&view/editor)

here's the code I'm using:

```
Ext.application({
name : 'Fiddle',

launch : function() {
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
        data:{'items':[
            { 'name': 'Lisa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-111-1224"  },
            { 'name': 'Bart',  "email":"bart@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1234" },
            { 'name': 'Homer', "email":"homer@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1244"  },
            { 'name': 'Marge', "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"  }
        ]},
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'items'
            }
        }
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: 'Simpsons',
        store: store,
        columns: [
            { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
            { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
            { text: 'Phone', width: 50, dataIndex: 'phone', cls: 'grid-header-phone' }
        ],
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
  }
});
```

and here's the css code:

```
.grid-header-phone .x-column-header-text {
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);

/* transform doesn't work on inline elements */
display: inline-block;

/* need to hard code a height for this to work */
/* you could use Ext.util.TextMetrics if you needed to dynamically determine the text size */
height: 40px;
}

.x-ie8 .grid-header-phone .x-column-header-text {
/* IE8 doesn't have css transform */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **display:inline-flex** instead of inline block.

Comment: I could remove the ellipses from the header by using inline-flex, where width is 50. Any width below 50 is making the row content disappear completely.